# Ruby/Selenium xpath html attribute

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, attributes

I need help

Is it possible to extract the value **Developer** from structure like this:

```
<h2 class="Title">
       WEB <em>Developer</em>    
</h2>
```

or like this (i need **bluh-bluh-bluh. *Developer* bluh bluh**):

```
<p class="Description">
        bluh-bluh-bluh. <em>Developer</em> bluh bluh
</p>
```

i have tried

```
title = driver.find_element(:css, ".******").attribute('????')
```

my command finds element, but not extract attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not *attribute*. Using proper selector and getting **text** should work

Selector: `h2>em`

**Use**

```
title = driver.find_element(:css, "h2>em").text
```